# запятая перед кавычками для обособления вводного сочетания

Tags: цитата

Газета пишет, что, «с точки зрения России, привычка военного вмешательства США, неоднократно использованная после холодной войны, вкупе с политическим давлением на суверенные государства - очевидные примеры жестокого вмешательства во внутренние дела».

Нужна ли запятая перед кавычками?

Ведь вводное *с точки зрения России* должно быть обособлено с двух сторон. Но смущает наличие кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужна ли запятая перед кавычками?

**Я бы не ставил.** Но...

См. обсуждение подобного примера (кстати, **ВАШЕГО** же!) и один из ответов Грамоты.ру:

http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5465

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%CD%E5+%E2%E8%E4%E8%EC+%F0%E0%E7%ED%E8%F6%FB+%EC%E5%E6%E4%F3+%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%E4%E5%ED%ED%FB%EC%E8+%C2%E0%EC%E8+%EF%F0%E8%EC%E5%F0%E0%EC%E8